# Javascript - If / Contains Condition

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a small piece of Javascript that I am using in an embedded VF page on Opportunities.  I would like to add a condition to check to see if the RecordType of the Opp is a certain group of values.  The code I have below does not work.  Can someone help me with the proper syntax for my Record Type line?

```
SFInitial.openWizard = function(){
            if(
                "{!Opportunity.StageName}" === "{!$Label.Eng_OppStage4}" &&
                "{!Opportunity.RecordType}.indexOf('Eng')" > "-1" &&
                "{!Opportunity.Includes__c}" !== "Yes" &&
                {!Opportunity.Stage_To_Contract__c}
            ){
                window.open(
                    "/apex/VFFormInit?Id={!Opportunity.Id}",
                    "newWindow2"
                );
            }

            return this;
```

Comment: The "-1" should be an integer -1 without the quotes. Also shouldn't it be `"{!Opportunity.RecordType}".indexOf('Eng')`. Better yet, just check the values in the controller if using one and set a boolean flag then use that

Comment: @Eric if it is put in the controller then you always need to go through a change process in order to make changes rather than just updating js

Comment: @EricSSH - OP said it was an inline page and thus I figured that the value for the parent app would not change and thus would always be as they were on load. If the parent values changed then most likely the page would be in edit mod / refreshed.... So I though it safe to suggest the controller part.

Comment: @Eric - Thanks.  There actually is no custom controller for the VF page.  It's just designed to open another VF page when the conditions are met in the JavaScript.  So my line would be: 
"{!Opportunity.RecordType.Name}".indexOf('Eng') > -1;

Comment: your last comment looks good - but if not, use console.log and display the values of the four merge fields before the `if` and inspect in Firebug or equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could be a simple expression, no controller necessary. You could change your JavaScript to:

```
 if({!Opportunity.StageName = $Label.Eng_OppStage4 &&
      CONTAINS(Opportunity.RecordType.Name, "Eng") &&
      Opportunity.Includes__c = "Yes" && 
      Opportunity.Stage_To_Contract__c}) {
 window.open(
             "{!URLFOR($Page.VFFormInit, null, [id=Opportunity.Id]}",
             "newWindow2"
            );
 }
```

This will result in the function being compiled into:

```
if(true) { ...
```

Or

```
if(false) { ...
```

Depending on if the conditions are true. This is usually FAR easier than trying to manipulate a mixture of merge fields and JavaScript (which you were apparently having problems with anyways).

One other thing to note, if you're going to be merging anything that doesn't evaluate to true or false, you probably want to also be using JSINHTMLENCODE to avoid possible XSS (Cross-Site Scripting) attacks, code injection, etc.